# mPDF - Footers - Content overlapping footers?

Tags: html, pdf, mpdf

We are using mpdf to create a pdf from a html page. We are setting up footers for all pages other then the first and last page. The footers will all be the same. The problem is the contents of the page is overlapping the footer. ie rather then the contents stopping just above the footer and going to the next page it goes all the way to the bottom of the page and overlaps the footer. Now, before you save pagebreak, the pdf page contents is somewhat dynamic and the length will vary from a few paragraphs to multiple changes, so not simply a case of putting in a page break.

Anyone done this before? know the secret?

Thank you

Answer (score 7):

Solved.. change margin bottom..

```
//$mpdf = new mPDF('',    // mode - default ''
//'A4',    // format - A4, for example, default ''
//0,     // font size - default 0
//'',    // default font family
//'',    // 15 margin_left
//'',    // 15 margin right
//25,     // 16 margin top
//55,    // margin bottom
//'',     // 9 margin header
//'',     // 9 margin footer
//'L');  // L - landscape, P - portrait
```